# Problem With File Reading - Can't get to display to console

Tags: java, string, io, printwriter

I'm currently working with `JFileChooser` and using it to write a file and then display the contents of the file. I don't really know how to describe my problem other than by showing an example of how I want my code to display in the console. I included my code at the bottom. My code runs just fine, I just can't figure out how to get the display how I want it to look. Could you please help me? (:

[image]

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.util.Scanner;
import javax.swing.JFileChooser;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;


public class PersonReader
{

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        try
        {
            PrintWriter out;
            File yourFile;
            JFileChooser fc = new JFileChooser();
            String line;
            String outFileName;
            String defaultFileName = "default.txt";
            int lineCount = 0;

            File workingDirectory = new File(System.getProperty("user.dir"));
            fc.setCurrentDirectory(workingDirectory);

            if (fc.showOpenDialog(null) == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION)
            {
                yourFile = fc.getSelectedFile();
                Scanner in = new Scanner(yourFile);

                outFileName = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Enter File Name: ");

                if (outFileName.trim().equals(""))
                {
                    outFileName = defaultFileName;
                }

                out = new PrintWriter(outFileName);

                while (in.hasNextLine())
                {
                    line = in.nextLine();

                    System.out.printf("\nLine %3d: %-30s", lineCount, line);
                    out.printf("Line %3d: %-30s\n", lineCount, line);
                }

                System.out.println();
                in.close();
                out.close();

            } else
            {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Cancelled by User.");
                System.exit(0);
            }

        } catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
            System.out.println("Error: File Not Found!");
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For your question this will work. Replace with your code.

```
out = new PrintWriter(outFileName);
String[] ar =new String[4];

while (in.hasNextLine())
{
    lineCount++;
    line = in.nextLine();

    if(lineCount==2){
        System.out.println("=========================================");
    }
    ar= line.split(","); 
    System.out.println(ar[0]+"\t"+ ar[1]+"\t"+ ar[2]+"\t"+ar[3] );

}
```

This is more like a logical question other than java.